# Add user to a repo in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, repository

I'm trying to add a user to have permissions for a repo I have recently setup. I've been able to add this same user to repos previously, it's not something that I do frequently though and looking at the [online documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-git-tfvc-repository-permissions?view=azure-devops) it show's a '+' button should be visible (see below)

[image]

However there is no '+' button visible to me (either initially or after I search and select the person I want to add), see below:

[image]

I do not believe any permissions have changed for my login since I last did this for another repo, so I wouldn't expect the '+' button to be hidden from me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just worked this out (was staring me in the face in fact) - basically they seem to have changed the UI; there's no '+' button now, the options appear to the left and altering these 'adds' the person to the repo!

[image]